# How to sample from a Multivatiate distribution with tensorflow probability

Tags: python, tensorflow

While I can simply sample from an ordinary t distribution like so:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf

tf.executing_eagerly() 


t = tfp.distributions.StudentT(2.0, 0.0, 1.0)
t.sample(10)
```

I fail to sample from a multivariate t distribution because of a tensorflow error

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import tensorflow as tf

tf.executing_eagerly() 

t = tfp.distributions.MultivariateStudentTLinearOperator(
    df=2.0,
    loc=tf.zeros(2),
    scale=tf.ones((2,2)),
)

t.sample(10)
```

> AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute > 'range_dimension'

The same exception persists if I use `tf.convert_to_tensor` or `tf.Variable` (which is what I actually would need to fit the degree of freedom from a given loc and covariance matrix).